# Facebook class not found in CakePHP 2

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

Downloaded the Facebook PHP SDK using composer in CakePHP 2 and included the folder location in `AppController`:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public function beforeFilter() {
        App::import('Vendor', 'Facebook/autoload.php');

        $this->Facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId'     =>  'myappid',
            'secret'    =>  'mysecretkey',
            'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
        ));
    }
```

**Error:**

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Facebook' not found in C:\wamp\www\rent\app\Controller\AppController.php on line 38 –
```

I have checked if the CURL extension is enabled in wampp server, and I confirm it is.

Comment: where is the error plz add in the question ?

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Facebook' not found in C:\wamp\www\rent\app\Controller\AppController.php on line 38

Comment: Please put this one App::import('Vendor', 'Facebook/autoload.php');
before class start and check it

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax to load `app/Vendor/Facebook/autoload.php` is:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'autoload', array('file' => 'Facebook/autoload.php'));
```

See the Cookbook for more information: [Loading Vendor Files](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files)

However, you have mentioned you have installed the package with `composer`. If this is the case, you only have to include the line:

```
require APP . 'Vendor/autoload.php';
```

in your `app/Config/bootstrap.conf` file, and whatever you install with `composer` will be automatically loaded. No need to load each individual class.

Comment: Thanks for your good comments... But i did followed this link http://www.idiotminds.com/login-with-facebook-using-php-sdk-in-cakephp/#comment-5660

Comment: Here, i was able to login the site with facebook username..but how to retrieve the email and full name. I included the email in the scope and set the access token but not email field returned ..only id and name was returned...really frustated...